# Divide groups of unordered lists into sub-groups of 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have groups of unordered lists and I am trying to divide each list group into sub-groups of 3 dynamically. So far I have this:

```
var uls = $("ul > li");
for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i+=3) {
uls.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<ul class='new'></ul>");
}
```

... for some sample HTML below

```
<h2>Group 1</h2>
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<h2>Group 2</h2>
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
<li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

The issue I am having is that my code just lumps all the `<ul>`s together without regard to groups, i.e. 'group 1' 'group 2' I tried using `.each(function() {` on `$("ul > li")` but I just get errors. I also tried moving down the each function after .length but that did not work either.

So the final HTML would look like this:

```
<h2>Group 1</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<h2>Group 2</h2>
    <ul>
etc...
```

[My fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/aXqwt/6/) but as you can see it's not quite working yet.

Comment: Just curious... what's with the downvote?

Comment: @AlecSanger ha? I don't see any downvotes...

Comment: That's because my upvote is bringing it back to 0...

Comment: @AlecSanger - I don't know why someone would downvote as I have this well documented and have tried stuff and they didn't even leave a comment why they downvoted it. Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/4Bms6/

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var uls = $("li", this);

    for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i+=3) {

    var lis = $("li", this);

        uls.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<ul class='new'></ul>");
    }
});​
```

The reason you were getting incorrect grouping is because you were starting off by collecting every single li ("ul > li" equates to all li that are children of any ul). What you should have been doing is selecting all li that are children of each ul, perform the grouping, then move on to the next ul.

Comment: yes, perfect >> http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/aXqwt/7/ Note I think you do not have the correct link in your answer, it's my old one.

Comment: I found that this ends up with `<ul>` tags within `<ul>`s, not sure if that is semantically correct. I can do: `$('ul ul').unwrap();` and that works to remove the extra original unneeded `<ul>` after the fact but I am guessing there might be a better way.